# With remote couchdb delete, corresponding pouchDB change event not triggered

Tags: typescript, couchdb, pouchdb

I am using a couchDb as remote master database. I am replicating it into the browser using pouchDb. And then doing live syncing, so that any change in my remote master databse gets synced in browser. With all insert/ update change event gets triggered and doc get updated. But when I am deleting a doc in master, delete not synced, not event "change" event gets triggered in the browser.

Is there any thing I am missing here?

```js
this.db.replicate.from(this.remoteDb, {
  view: this.remoteView,
});

this.db
  .sync(this.remoteDb, {
     live: true,
     retry: true,
     pull: true,
     push: false,
     view: this.remoteView,
   })
   .on("change", info => {
        console.log("change from sync", info);
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are doing a filtered replication based on a view's map function. 
In this case, if your perform a DELETE over a document the document content is removed, so the information required by the filter is missing and it is not included in the filtered change stream.

With filtered replications you should delete documents by updating the documents including the attribute `"_deleted":true`. In this case, the document content is preserved and can be incluided in the filtered change stream.